# how to pass dynamic array of object values to select2 package on vue.js2

Tags: arrays, object, select, vuejs2, jquery-select2

i want to make a searchable select on vue.js2, so i found package called "select2"
i could make it work if its options are on a single array
but i had an array of object, and i want just specific values of that object to be like options of select

```
<div>
   <Select2 v-model="form.user_id" 
            :options="UsersNumbers"
   />
 </div>

  UsersNumbers: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

and the array of objects comes from backend

i tried to access the "msisdn" value in each object inside the array this way:

```
<div>
   <Select2 v-model="form.user_id" 
            :options="UsersNumbers.msisdn"
   />
 </div>
```

but it doesn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed the values or form of the actual `UsersNumbers` you're using, but take for example an array of objects like this

```js
this.UsersNumbers = [
  { name: 'foo', msisdn: '1' },
  { name: 'bar', msisdn: '2' },
  { name: 'baz', msisdn: '3' }
]
```

From this array of objects you can create an array of single values using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
computed: {
  msisdns() {
    return this.UsersNumbers.map(u => u.msisdn) // returns ['1', '2', '3']
  }
}
```

[computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) is used here to reactively update whenever `UsersNumbers` changes due to your backend fetch

Then just use this computed property with your select

```html
<Select2 v-model="form.user_id" 
  :options="msisdns"
/>
```